# Designating Headers in Flextable from Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, flextable

I have a tibble with Station Codes, Species, Days Present and Percent of Days present

```
tibble <- data.frame(
  station_code = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  species_name = c("Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2", "Species3", "Species3"),
  days_present = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35),
  percent_days_present = c(50, 75, 80, 90, 60, 70))
```

I'd like to make a flextable that looks like this (data wise, not style):

[image]

EDIT: for reasons I don't understand, my original test data was not close enough to my actual data. This is the more accurate data

```
tibble2 <- data.frame(
  station_code = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
  species_name = c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4"),
  days_present = c(10,15,20,25,30,35,20,35),
  percent_days_present = c(50,75,80,90,60,70,25,45))
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"data wise, not style"*? Do you want a flextable or you want to split your data like that? Something like this maybe: ```split(subset(df, select=-species_name), df$species_name```

Comment: I meant I made this example table in word, and I'm not looking for it to LOOK like that, just to arrange the data in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a flextable like that:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)


df %>% 
  arrange(species_name) %>% 
  rename(Station = "station_code", `Days Present` = "days_present", 
         `% Days Present` = "percent_days_present") %>% 
  as_grouped_data(., groups = "species_name", columns = NULL) %>% 
  as_flextable(hide_grouplabel = TRUE) %>% 
  set_header_labels(what = "") %>% 
  bold( bold = TRUE, part="header") %>% 
  align(i = ~ !is.na(species_name), align = "center") %>% 
  bold(i = ~ !is.na(species_name)) %>% 
  width(., width = 1.5)
```

[image]

But if you just want to split your data:

```r
split(subset(df, select=-species_name), df$species_name, drop = T)
#> $Species1
#>   station_code days_present percent_days_present
#> 1            A           10                   50
#> 2            B           15                   75
#> 
#> $Species2
#>   station_code days_present percent_days_present
#> 3            A           20                   80
#> 4            B           25                   90
#> 
#> $Species3
#>   station_code days_present percent_days_present
#> 5            A           30                   60
#> 6            B           35                   70
```

##### Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  station_code = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  species_name = c("Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2", "Species3", "Species3"),
  days_present = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35),
  percent_days_present = c(50, 75, 80, 90, 60, 70))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: your code works perfectly on the test data, but on my actual data it shows each individual species heads each individual station, rather than grouping the stations... but I'm not sure how my test data is different than the original

Comment: I updated my question with more "accurate" test data (which behaved the same as my original data)

Comment: @GabrielleMacklin you need to sort your data. I added `arrange(species_name) %>%`, see above.

Comment: yes, that worked!! Thank you so very much!